# Save Date close app

Tags: android

See who can help. I want that when closing the application I save the date of the datepicker so that when it reopens open. Can you help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView et1, et2, et3;

    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.et2);

        et1.setText("");
        et2.setText("");
    }

    public void inttroduce_fecha(View v) {

        final Calendar dateIni = Calendar.getInstance();

        mYear = dateIni.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = dateIni.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = dateIni.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, (dayOfMonth));
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        String dateString = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                        et1.setText(dateString);

                        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, (dayOfMonth+28));
                        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        String dateString1 = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                        et2.setText(dateString1);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: one word `SharedPreference`

Comment: I do not know how to start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score 0):

Not found, why?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView et1, et2;

```
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

private String MY_PREFS_NAME = "mypref";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.et2);

    et1.setText("");
    et2.setText("");

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    editor.putInt("idName", 12);
    editor.apply();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        int et1 = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
    }

}

public void inttroduce_fecha(View v) {

    final Calendar dateIni = Calendar.getInstance();

    mYear = dateIni.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = dateIni.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = dateIni.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, (dayOfMonth));
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    String dateString = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                    et1.setText(dateString);

                    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, (dayOfMonth+28));
                    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    String dateString1 = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                    et2.setText(dateString1);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

}